# Kafka Producer - Trace Kerberos user

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, kafka-producer-api

In a kerberized set-up with a Kafka cluster I can easily enforce that for topic X, Users A and B have the right to produce messages, and for topic Y, User C has the right to produce messages.

In terms of traceability, this gives me the guarantee that all messages on topic Y are produced by User C. However, I would also like to know which messages on topic X were produced by User A, and which messages were produced by User B.

Is there an option to tag each message with the user that produced it? With one remark perhaps, that I do not want to do this on the producer-side but would like to enforce it broker-side so I have an absolute guarantee that this user information is present.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there currently is a way to do that to be honest. The only two pluggable classes in the broker that I know of are the KafkaPrincipalBuilder and the Authorizer, both of which have the principal you are after, but do not have access to the actual records to add the principal in a header field or wherever one would want it.

And even if we look to the producer side, the two options there would be Interceptor and Serializer classes that you can customize, both of which have access to the records, but not the user principal.

If you actually want to enforce this I'm afraid you'll have to become a bit creative and do something like have them sign every message with a private key in a header field or something similar - when processing data on the other end you can then discard anything that doesn't contain a that field.

Apart from that I think there is not much you can do except actually changing Kafka itself to add this information - in general [the handleProduceRequest method](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaApis.scala#L400) should be a good starting place, here you have the requests that have been authorized and can also access the requests session which contains the principal. Records are only represented as bytebuffers here though, not sure whether you can easily headers at this point tbh..